# Push notification does not appear if app is in background on iOS 9

Tags: ios, push-notification, ios9

I'm having an issue with push notifications and it affects only my devices running iOS 9:

1. I have my app installed in a set of devices. I run it and register for push notifications with the following code:

```objectivec
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

2. The app is put on background on all devices.
3. I send push notifications to all devices - and get the response that it succeeded.
4. All iOS 8 devices display the push notification in the notification center.
5. NO iOS 9 device display the push notification in the notification center.
6. Open the app in any of the iOS 9 devices in some random moment. The notification is displayed (triggered by `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`).

Has anything changed on iOS 9? How can I make the push notifications display also on iOS 9, even if the app is not active?
I don't want to use notifications to fetch any content in background, I just need to display a message.

Comment: Just to clarify, a successful "send" response doesn't mean that the devices received the push, it just means that the message was well formed, the certificates matched etc.  Push notifications aren't guaranteed to be delivered

Comment: @Paulw11 You're right about that, I edited my question just to avoid confusion. Anyways, I've tested many times and it always behaves like that: push notification is "sent" and it only appears if I open the app, which is weird. It should appear even if the app is in background. It should be displayed in the notification center.

Comment: @JobertSá I have the same issue. Do you finally succeed to fix it?

Comment: @Thomi Yes, I've just posted my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36898516/564532 Maybe it will help in your case as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I had to do two things that made it work for me:

- Enable "**Remote Notifications**" for Background Modes under the Application capabilities (in the target settings)
- Send the notifications with high priority (when they were sent with low priority, they were not being handled with the application on background)

Comment: The notification DOES appear in the notification center of the device BUT the app delegate method `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)` is NOT CALLED until the notification is not tapped by the user in the notification center. I think it is the normal behaviour, could you please confirm that you have this result?

Comment: @Thomi That's expected behavior.
If you want to do something when the app is in background, when the notification is received, you need to implement also `application(_didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`
Besides, you need to enable "Remote Notifications" as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Yes, and the notification needs to have "content-available" property set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are OK. This is my code, i get notification in iOS 9.0 also.

```
-(void)registarPushNotification:(UIApplication*)application
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {    
        UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |  UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

        UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications]; 
    }
    else
    {
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the user has to tap the notification to bring the app to the foreground and then `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)` will be called.

See here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial